# phpDesigner ошибка при подключении к SFTP

Tags: linux, debian, sftp

phpDesigner выдаёт ошибку при подключении:

> Server does not support diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 for keyexchange

Пробовал прописывать в конфиг `sshd_config`

```
kexalgorithms diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

К серверу вообще перестает подключаться.

В чем проблема? WinSCP нормально подключается.

Comment: там, откуда подключаетесь, видимо, очень древний *openssh-client*.

Answer (score 1):

1. после внесения **таких** изменений необходимо создать недостающие в `/etc/ssh` ключи:

   ```
   $ cd /etc/ssh
   $ sudo ssh-keygen -A
   ```
2. вот [тут](https://www.veeam.com/kb2061) рекомендуют добавить и другие алгоритмы и *ciphers*-ы, т.е., строка для `kexalgorithms`:

   ```
   kexalgorithms diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
   ```

   и ещё одна строка для `ciphers`:

   ```
   ciphers 3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes128-cbc,aes128-ctr,aes256-ctr
   ```
3. а вообще, конечно, лучше обновить этот самый *phpdesigner*.